# How to retreive the jquery ajax response received

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Jquery code:

```
     $("#sub").click(function(){
        var country = $('#sel-country :selected').text();
        var university = $('#sel-university :selected').text();
        var level = $('#sel-level :selected').text();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getUsers.php',
                type: 'post',           
                data: { country:country,
                        university:university,
                        level:level
                      },           
                success:function(response1){
                },      
            });
        });
    });
```

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['university']) && isset($_POST['country']) ){

 $university = $_POST['university'];
 $country = $_POST['country'];
 $level = $_POST['level'];
 $sql="SELECT Distinct course FROM courses where 
 university='".$university."' and level ='".$level. "'"  ;
 $results=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql) or die("Cannot execute query");
 $count=mysqli_num_rows($results);
 $users_arr = array();
 while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results) ){
 $course = $row['course'];
 $users_arr[] = array("course" => $course);  
 }
  echo json_encode($users_arr);
 }
```

when i console the response i get the below output

```
 [{"University":"Wuhan"},{"University":"CTGU"}][{"course":"MD"},{"course":"MS"}]
```

I have not specified Datatype and not done json parse for the response
If i do so i am getting error like

```
t1.php:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [ in JSON at position 46
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
at Object.success (t1.php:77)
at j (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:2)
at x (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4)
```

Please help to fix this issue...

Comment: Its an array of objects.                                                      [{"University":"Wuhan"},{"University":"CTGU"}][{"course":"MD"},{"course":"MS"}]   is not valid json format.                                                            Where you have set the JSON, format it on JSONLint.org

Comment: @varshaghodki in fact it seems to be 2 arrays, but there's no comma between them - I'm guessing `position 46` is the opening square bracket of the second array - it's expecting a comma.

Comment: what does `$users_arr` look like?

Comment: Why you encode format if you don't want to return result in JSON format?

Comment: then how can i return that array to juery?? this is the array i have done file write before json encoding....  Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [course] => MD
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [course] => MS
        )

)

Comment: I want to know how the content of `$users_arr` looks like **before** you json_encode it, just call the script manually and replace `echo json_encode($users_arr)` with `print_r($users_arr)`.

Comment: @KallumTanton, Yes, that's why  I said the format is not correct. I am not sure whether he has created to show us or simply logged from the response.

Comment: This return proper format if you pass dataType: 'json' in your ajax call.

Comment: @varshaghodki Based on the OPs wording it looks like this is direct from the console so you're right - counting the characters in the response to number 46 brings you to that square bracket.

Comment: @TobiasF. Array ( [0] => Array ( [course] => MD ) [1] => Array ( [course] => MS )

Comment: It seems strange to me something like is is returned by `json_encode()`, there shouldn't be any problems when encoding this simple Array. Edit: Is the missing `,` between the two inner arrays a typo?